# Draw route openstreet maps

Tags: openstreetmap

I have several geo points witch I want to use to draw a route using the openstreet maps. Where can I start is there any documentation for this map ?

Thanks

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routes

Comment: How do you want to draw them? As a simple overlay on top of already existing map tiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to plot routes on OSM. JXMapViewer is good if you're coding in java and should allow you to do whatever you want.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JXMapViewer2